# MongoDB Administration

Tags: javascript, mongodb, csv

I am trying to import a simple CSV file using mongoimport. The command I used was

> mongoimport --db mydb --collection Test --type csv --file C:\Users\Jawahir\Des
>   ktop/Test.csv

where I created the collection named Test.Also, I created a csv file named Test.CSV which has the following details

FirstName   LastName    Age Position    Experience
Jawahir Junaith 27  SE  4.2
Javeed  A   24  Network Admin   1
Abdul   Waheed  54  Teacher 23
7

I am getting error lie "Javascript Ececution Failed: Syntax error

What is the issue here ?

Answer (score 1):

You're running this in the mongo shell. Mongoimport is a separate executable. Exit the shell then try the command again.